# tkinter askdirectory button text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using tkinter's `askdirectory()` in Python 3 and have a couple questions:

- Is it possible to change the text box label from "Select Folder" to a custom literal?
- Some of the folders that I am displaying using `askdirectory()` contains a ".xx" in the folder name.  Is there any way to display folders with the .xx removed?
  (Thinking this isn't possible but wanted to make sure...)

Here's sample code for how I'm using the function:

```
search_directory = 'C:\\temp\\'

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=search_directory,
                                        title = "Choose Folder")
```

Comment: Please clarify your first question. What do you mean a custom literal? You can make the title reflect any string you want.

Comment: To clarify, I'd like the button title to say "Choose Operation" instead of "Select Folder".  How can I reference the particular button and change the label?

Comment: Ok please update your question to reflect you want the Button to change text. That is different from a label and a title.

Comment: I have been digging into the source code and searching the web. I am not sure you can do either of the things you are asking. It might be possible if you create a customer `askdirectory()` class but that would be a large amount of work to be able to change the text on a button.